# Проблема с выключением и гибернацией

Tags: linux

Пытался запустить ОС Linux с загрузочной флешки. Bios не в какую не хотел ее запускать, пришлось откатить его к дефолтным настройкам.

Далее загрузочная флешка нормально запустилась и отработала. ОС на ней уже была предустановлена, поэтому я ничего не устанавливал, а работал с нее. По окончании вышел с linux, вытащил флешку и перешел на дефолтную винду, 
На следующий день заметил, что на моей основной ос (win10) перестала отрабатывать кнопка "завершение работы" и режим гибернации.

Кнопку выключения починил путем снятия галочки с параметра "Включить быстрый запуск" в настройках электропитания. С гибернацией пока большой вопрос. Выставлял уже в Bios исходные настройки итог: гибернация все равно не работает.

Собственно, хотел бы узнать в чем причина и как вернуть работоспособность гибернации?

Ноутбук: DEXP Achiles G113

Он же: Clevo W65_67SC

Comment: поищите файл hiberfil.sys на жестком диске, скорее всего его нет

Comment: Искал. На жестком диске его нет.
Скорее всего должен создаваться командой включения гибернации powercfg -h on, но не создается.

Comment: попробуйте в командную строку от имени админа ввести powercfg –hibernate –on

Comment: Уже пробовал. В реестре тоже все перепроверил. Предполагаю, что проблема на уровне bios.

Comment: а по этому пути проходить тоже пробовали?HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Power

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich Да, проходил. Там все без проблем